# Deploy and test Golang hello function locally on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I get hello app by **Export function** from AWS lambda,

```
$ ls -tlr
total 1480
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xiaojie xiaojie 1512248  7月 12  2018 hello
$ ./hello
```

- how to test it? I don't know the port and API of it. how can I send JSON to it?
- Where I can get some info, a manual, source codes about it?

Comment: I think you just donwloaded the binary from the hello world, if you want an example of golang lambda function check this https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go

Comment: Also you should consider watching some videos about lambda as it does not behave as a classical server